Proving for n+1 and n-1 at the same time using induction.
I was solving:
If $z + z^{-1} = 2 \cos \alpha$, prove that $z^n + z^{-n} = 2\cos (n\alpha)$, $(z \in \mathbb{C},\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N})$
This can be solved using De Moivre's formula, but i decided to solve it using induction:
Base case: given in the task
We assume that $z^n + z^{-n} = 2\cos (n\alpha)$ is true, and try to prove $z^{n+1} + z^{-(n+1)} = 2\cos ((n+1)\alpha)$:
$z^n + z^{-n} = 2\cos (n\alpha)$
$(z^n + z^{-n})(z + z^{-1}) = 2\cos (n\alpha) * 2\cos \alpha$
$(z^{n+1} + \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}) + (z^{n-1} + \frac{1}{z^{n-1}}) = 2 \cos{((n+1)\alpha)} + 2\cos{((n-1)\alpha)}$
Does this count as a complete proof?
Can we prove for both $n+1$ and $n-1$ in the same induction step?
P.S. Can someone show how this could this be done using De Moivre's formula?

Hello, use $$\begin{align*}z^{n+2}+z^{-(n+2) }&=(z+z^{-1}) (z^{n+1}+z^{-(n+1) }) -(z^n+z^{-n})\&=2\cos(\alpha)\cdot2\cos((n+1)\alpha)-2\cos(n\alpha)\end{align*}$$

In the proof, can we claim that $z=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$ or do we have to only rely on the given condition that $z+z^{-1}=2\cos\alpha$?

Yes! That works, although another line might be helpful. What you are using here is called strong induction. Which is, over the natural numbers, equivalent to induction.
Let’s say you’re trying to prove $\forall n P(n)$. Induction says that you can show $P(0)$ and also show
$$\forall n (P(n) \implies P(n+1)) $$
Strong induction says that you can change your inductive step to
$$\forall n ((\forall m<n \; P(m))\implies P(n))$$
Do you see how that works for what you did?
One last thing, your proof fails for $n=1$. You need two base cases.

Your answer is correct if you use strong induction, i.e assuming $z^k +z^{-k} = 2cos(nα)$ for all $k \leq n$ Which gives you the n-1 step for free.
I tried usind De Moivre but had to asume $|z|=1$. Let $z=e^{iα}=cos(α) +isen(α)$.
Since $arg(z) + arg(z^{-1}) = 2πk$ for some integer k, you can asume without loss of generality that $arg(z^{-1}) = -α$ (this works because the periodicity of trig functions) Then:
$$ z^n + z^{-n} = cos(nα) + isen(n\alpha) + cos(-nα) + isen(-nα) = 2cos(nα)$$
This is fairly simple if $|z|=|z^{-1}|=1$ if not, $|z|=r$ gives you $$ z^n + z^{-n} = (r + r^{-1})cos(nα) + i(r-r^{-1})sen(n\alpha)$$
Wich I couldnt further simplify.

$|z|$ has to be equal to $1$ only, because the right hand side is always less than or equal to $2$
